# Component not visible in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, paint

I have JPanel in a container of a JFrame called Box

```
public Box(){
        add(new Ball());
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(OFFSET, OFFSET, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(OFFSET, OFFSET, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }
```

Ball extends Component and draws a ball

```
public class Ball extends Component{
   ...
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(xCoord, yCoord, radius, radius);
}
   ...
}
```

When I add a Box with a Ball to the container I can only ever see the Box. If I just add a Ball I can see the Ball.

Does anyone know why the Ball is not visible when added to a Box?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do not mix heavyweight and lightweight components. You should be extending [`JComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) instead.
2. You should be overriding `paintComponent()`, not `paint()`.
3. Does `Ball` have a size? If you haven't supplied `Ball` with a `Dimension`, it won't be visible.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to overriding `paintComponent`, use a LayoutManager to set bounds automatically. For testing purposes, you can set the LayoutManager of the `Box` instance to null and use `setBounds` on the `Ball` instance.

Comment: The ball did have a size of zero and unfortunately the user who told me this has deleted their answer. This was the problem and it is now fixed.

Comment: @Alex, I undeleted my answer, if you wanted to accept it. But regardless, I'm glad your problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In Swing, you should normally never override the `paint` method. Use `paintComponent` instead.

Comment: Then we will need a complete example (see the link in Andrew's comment).

Answer (score 1):

there are three possible mistake

1/ simpliest paint by using `JLabel`

2/ timing by `javax.swing.Timer`

3/ `paintComponents` instead of `paint` (for `AWT Compoents` and painting `DefaultXxxUI`)

and put that together, for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AnimationJPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int cx = 0;
    private int cy = 150;
    private int cw = 20;
    private int ch = 20;
    private int xinc = 1;
    private int yinc = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                AnimationJPanel panel = new AnimationJPanel();
                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
                panel.animate();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public AnimationJPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel("This is an AnimationJPanel");
        label.setForeground(Color.RED);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(label);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setForeground(Color.RED);
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    public void animate() {
        new Timer(15, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Rectangle oldCircle = new Rectangle(cx - 1, cy - 1, cw + 2, ch + 2);
                cx += xinc;
                cy += yinc;
                if (cx >= getWidth() - cw || cx <= 0) {
                    xinc *= -1;
                }
                if (cy >= getHeight() - ch || cy <= 0) {
                    yinc *= -1;
                }
                repaint(oldCircle);
                repaint(cx - 1, cy - 1, cw + 2, ch + 2);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(cx, cy, cw, ch);
    }
}
```